# visiting a dynamic link that opened in new tab in cypress

Tags: automation, cypress

Scenario:

While clicking a link/button in the application, a new tab is opened (with a dynamic url)

Is there a way in cypress to test somethings in the newly opened tab?

I cannot use `cy.visit()` as the url generated will be different each time

Answer (score 0):

[Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Multiple-tabs) is very specific about it - Cypress doesn't have and will never have support for multi tabs.

However, they also provide plenty of workarounds for it. Please check [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/testing-dom__tab-handling-links) - there is plenty of example code for multiple cases, so you may choose what suits you best.
Hope it helps